# Q: SwiftUI - navigationBarTitle transparent error

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationlink

UPDATE: Resolved - This topic is just a beta bug.

I'm having a problem with the navigationBarTitle in SwiftUI. 
I'm using a NavigationLink to go to a second view with a list. This view has a navigationBarTitle like the first view. But in the second view I can push the list behind the navigationBarTitle.
[image: Bad BarTitle]

When I'm going from a third view back to the second the navigationBarTitle works as it should be.
[image: Good BarTitle]

Does anyone else having this problem? I'm using Xcode Version 11.0 GM (11A419c)

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var line : [String] = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(line, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                        TestCell(lineName: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("Main View")
        }
    }
}

struct TestCell: View {
    let lineName: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(lineName)
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailDetailView()) {
                Text("To the next view")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Detail View")
    }
}

struct DetailDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")

            .navigationBarTitle("Detail Detail View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like another bug.

Comment: It works fine in a simulator. I have the same version of Xcode.

Comment: @FRIDDAY Strange.. which version of Catalina do you have?

Comment: @HeGe Catalina version is  Beta (19A558d) and Xcode Version 11.0 GM (11A419c). try it with Xcode GM Seed 2. however your code works perfectly on my Xcode.